# Reclaim space after aborted git add?

Tags: git

I accidentally git added a large (32GB) file to my staging area. After a handful of seconds I noticed (my fans spun up!) and hit CTRL+C. This stopped the process but the ~2GB of space it had used has not been returned to the file system.

How can I reclaim that space? Not that I'm short of a gig or two but having big useless clots of data knocking around somewhere (presumably in my .git folder) bothers me.

I've looked a git clean but that doesn't look like it will help.

The files it has added are...

```
1.9G    ./objects/pack
1.9G    ./objects/pack/tmp_pack_lwma1r
```

Can I safely delete these?

Comment: pack is a dirrr

Comment: @gauteh - yes, yes it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 git reflog expire --expire=now --all
 git fsck --full --unreachable
 git repack -A -d
 git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

This will do a bunch of cleaning on the repo. Specifically, I think `git repack` is the one that will really solve your problem. The others won't hurt, though.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work in this case. I have updated the question to show the files that have been created.

Comment: I've updated the answer to a more aggressive approach.

Comment: Thanks very much, the last line of the four was the one that got rid of it. Happily it also seems to have dealt with my "dangling blobs" !!!